# Is this determinacy principle consistent?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, determinacy, infinite-games

Let $\mathsf{ODet}_{\omega_1}(L(\mathbb{R}))$ be the following principle ("determinacy for simple open length-$\omega_1$ games"):

> If $\kappa$ is any ordinal and $X\subseteq \kappa^{<\omega_1}$ is in $L(\mathbb{R})$, then the game of length $\omega_1$ on $\kappa$ with payoff set $$[X]:=\{f\in\kappa^{\omega_1}: \exists\alpha\in\omega_1(f\upharpoonright\alpha\not\in X)\}$$ is determined in $V$.

My question is whether $\mathsf{ODet}_{\omega_1}(L(\mathbb{R}))$ is consistent relative to large cardinals. I recall seeing a while ago a proof that the answer is yes, relative to something like a proper class of Woodins, but I can't track it down. (I'm pretty sure I can prove that this principle is equivalent to its clopen game analogue, but that's no easier to prove consistent as far as I can tell.) Neeman's work on long games is the most relevant I can find, but doesn't seem to directly address this unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't your principle imply $\text{AD}_{\omega_1}$ for games of length $\omega$ using countable ordinal moves? If so, it is inconsistent. That is, for $\kappa=\omega_1$, I seem to be able to mimic games on countable ordinals of length $\omega$ in your context. But there is a nondetermined such game.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Doesn't such a game have payoff set not in $L(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: $\text{AD}_{\omega_1}$ is inconsistent with ZF, which holds in $L(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Ah, you mean the strategy might not be in $L(\mathbb{R})$. I see.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, the game's payoff set needs to be in $L(\mathbb{R})$, but the strategy just has to live in $V$.

Comment: If you can force a strategy without adding reals, then just add those by force.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Regarding your first comment above, the relevant games for refuting $\text{AD}_{\omega_1}$ do have payoff sets in $L(\mathbb{R})$, so the main point should be about the strategies, not the payoff sets. Namely, the relevant game is player I plays a countable ordinal $\alpha$ and player II plays a real code for it. This game has payoff set in $L(\mathbb{R})$. Player I can't win, but if player II has a winning strategy, there is an $\omega_1$-sequence of distinct reals, which would contradict AD in $L(\mathbb{R})$ if the strategy were in $L(\mathbb{R})$. But in your case, it isn't.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Ah yes, sorry, I was sloppy.